# Parse XML string with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I know this looks like a very repeated question, but I have been searching for two days and I didn't find where my code fails. I'm trying to parse an XML from a string.

If I use the $.parseXML everything goes well except for one item element called "content:encoded". For some reason, JQuery can't find it. If I don't use the $.parseXML, and I try to just do $(data) then, that field is found, but other problem arises (many of the other fields are not found). I posted a live example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/danielo515/q3XLf/1/

And here is the function responsible of parsing the XML

```
function executeQuery(data,itemDesc){
     var result = [],
         xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data), //if I remove this line, content\\:encoded works
         $xml = $(xmlDoc),
         elements = itemDesc.elements;
        $xml.find(itemDesc.name).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
            item = {};
            for(var el in elements){
                item[el] = $this.find(elements[el]).text();
            }
            //Do something with item here...
            result.push(item); 
        });

     return result;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At the end using the last part of the tag name worked. This mean, for  I used:

```
$this.find("encoded").text();
```

All the other options that I found, such as '[elementName="content:encoded"]' didn't worked.